# sql server database size shown different in properties pane

Tags: sql-server-2012, disk-space

while monitoring when checking  database space used,my favorites are

```
use indexinternals
sp_spaceused
```

[image]

`select (sum(size)*8)/1024 as size From sys.master_files where name like 'indexinternals%'`

[image]

but for a curiosity I also checked the properties of database 
but when I take the properties of the database its shows the size **380MB**
[image]

Its just different on this database only ,all other databases shows correct values.Any suggestion where to look at and why its showing like that ?

Comment: Tried issuing UPDATEUSAGE command http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188414.aspx ? I'm sure you have also already "refreshed" your connection in SSMS. A few things I have seen work, but generally I keep with the query output versus SSMS.

Comment: @ShawnMelton,I will give it a try but before that, I suspect the Properties pane results are wrong because when I checked the physical space used on harddrive, it shows only 300mb(row+log)

Comment: @ShawnMelton,given a shot to UPDATEUSAGE ,but didn't solved

Comment: It is not something new with SSMS GUI being out of sync with the actual metadata. Me personally, even though it may bug me a bit, I would move on to bigger issues.

Answer (score 2):

Properties dialog shows data and log file size. It's the same as `sp_spaceused` without any arguments. Use `sp_spaceused table` returns size of the table (i.e., part of data file) - it never takes into account transaction log - that's the missing part in the discrepancy you see.

Comment: It does include logfile space: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx